# How do I add location to formula for calculation in Netsuite Saved Search

Tags: formula, netsuite

[image]

The following formula works fine to calculate the Fill Rate % for the shippable value / total.

`sum(case when ({quantitycommitted} is not null AND ({quantity} - {quantitypacked}) \>0) then {quantitycommitted}\*{rate} ELSE 0 end)/NULLIF(SUM(({quantity} - {quantityshiprecv}) \* {rate}),0)`

But, when I add the transaction location, I get the fillable % against the total, not the location total.

`sum(case when ({quantitycommitted} is not null AND ({quantity} - {quantitypacked}) \>0) AND ({location} = 'Norcross') then {quantitycommitted}\*{rate} ELSE 0 end)/CASE WHEN (({location} = 'Norcross') THEN NULLIF(SUM(({quantity} - {quantityshiprecv}) \* {rate}),0) END)`

[image]

Tried several variations of including the location field, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is both a location field and an `{inventorylocation}` field. For this calculation you want `{inventorylocation}`

You may see older examples where the `location` field is used.

The location field is the body level field used for setting access permissions.

Comment: Thank you!  I do not thinkit is a correct field issue.  The folllowing formula works when the sales order has the specific location:
sum(case when {location} = 'Perris' AND ({quantitycommitted} >0 AND ({quantity} - {quantitypacked}) > 0)  then ({quantitycommitted}*{rate})  ELSE 0 end)

The issue is proper syntax to include the location field in the more complex formula above.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the part about the locations. I've added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the formula is what is causing this. You are using the Maximum summary column to trigger the aggregate functions in your formula. This makes aggregate functions in the formula work on the whole set.

so try this:

- instead of Maximum use Sum
- alter your formula to something like:

```sql
case 
    when ({quantitycommitted} is not null 
        AND ({quantity} - {quantitypacked}) >0) 
        AND ({location} = 'Norcross') 
    then {quantitycommitted} * {rate} ELSE 0 end
```

- and

```sql
CASE WHEN ({location} = 'Norcross') 
    THEN {quantity} - {quantityshiprecv}) * nullif({rate},0) end
```

Comment: Thank you kindly sir!  I really appreciate it. I managed to work the formula with the Maximum summary.  They only want one row to appear and if you use SUM, it displays a total line.  To fix, I just kept trying variations of inserting the "IF {location} =" formula.   The final looks like this:   `sum(case when {location} = 'Norcross' AND ({quantitycommitted} is not null AND ({quantity} - {quantitypacked}) >0) then {quantitycommitted}*{rate} ELSE 0 end)/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN {location} = 'Norcross' THEN ({quantity} - {quantityshiprecv}) * {rate} END),0)`

Comment: I am new Stackoverflow, so if I did not post that correctly, apologies.

Comment: No worries, Given your final answer I still didn't read it quite correctly. 
You should post your comment as an answer and then accept it so that there will be one correct answer on this question. My answers may help someone else so I won't remove them.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, I just kept trying variations of inserting the "IF {location} =" formula.
The final looks like this:
sum(case when {location} = 'Norcross' AND ({quantitycommitted} is not null AND ({quantity} - {quantitypacked}) >0) then {quantitycommitted}*{rate} ELSE 0 end)/NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN {location} = 'Norcross' THEN ({quantity} - {quantityshiprecv}) * {rate} END),0)

Comment: can you please format your code for a better lisibility ?